# Unable to view deployed Liferay portlet in the add >> more option

Tags: liferay, portlet

I have created a sample Liferay portlet and it has successfully deployed. But, the eclipse console didn't say "1 portlet is ready for use". And, I couldn't find this portlet in the Add >> More.. option on a Liferay page.

Comment: Give more details, put e.g. the log output here.

Comment: INFO: Deploying web application directory library-portlet
This is being displayed in the Eclipse console. But, 'Loading File:' is not displayed which happened for all the other available liferay portlets.

Answer (score 5):

As [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597624/mark) mentioned, it is undeterministic and it sometimes happen. I usually follow the following steps and after this it works normally.

**Steps:**

1. remove all the references of the portlet from webapps.
2. stop the server
3. deploy the portlet's WAR
4. restart the server
5. check the logs if the portlet is deployed.

If possible try to build the WAR again and deploy the new WAR, and follow the previous steps.

Also if this doesn't work try to clear the `temp` and `work` directory and again try the previous steps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Prakash
Meanwhile, I've gone through Liferay in Action and started doing everything on command line. i.e., without using IDE. Everything worked fine except the java.sql.SQLException: No suitable Driver and Acquisition Attempt failed!!! message.
I've gone through the related posts but couldn't get any useful information.
- I could view the example portlets provided by the author.
- I've an user account which has all the previliges for the 'lportal' database.
- Liferay tables are also created in the database.
- There is also mysql.jar file in lib\ext folder.

Comment: Liferay in action is a good guide. By can you please tell when are you getting the exception?: 1) when u deploy the portlet 2) when you restart the server 3) when you access your portlet 4) when you access any liferay portlets.

Comment: Liferay is unable to access MySQL. When I include portal-ext.properties file, and restart the server, I'm getting exceptions and I'm unable to access liferay. If I remove the properties file and access liferay using default Hypersonic database, everything is working fine. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: can you edit your question and provide Liferay and mysql version info. Also if its CE or EE you are using. If possible can also include the error stack-trace you are getting. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have been fighting with this problem for a day. For me it was two things: wrong property of

```
liferay.home
```

inside

```
portal-setup-wizard.properties
```

Only after correction I was able too see in tomcat logs that my liferay-plugins had higher version than liferay itself. I redownload plugins with correct version and new plugin deployed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you've done all the cleaning etc. and it still does not work, there may be another reason for not showing. If you have - for some reson - deactivated the portlet in Liferay, it will remember the setting even though you have undeployed it several times.

So, you must go to *Control Panel > App Manager > All Apps > Your portlet name* and activate it again!

Answer (score 1):

That is undeterministc but usual error. Try to undeploy the portlet - delete portlet directory under `tomcat/webapps` and try to deploy again.

Comment: Sorry Mark, it was not successful. Tried that many times but the situation didn't change.