# Liferay on Glassfish. Spring portlet is deployed successfully but not showing up in the Liferay "Add Application" list

Tags: deployment, glassfish, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I'm using Liferay 6.1.2 on Glassfish 3.2.2. I'm able to deploy Spring portlet successfully (A working and verified portlet on the previous glassfish/liferay build) but it is not showing up in the Liferay "Add Application" list.
I've checked the xml namespace declarations, liferay xml files (portlet, display) and all seem to be compliant with the liferay specs. The logs do not show any errors but I did notice that the logs were NOT showing the "x portlets are available for use" message as it used to in the previous build.

Comment: I hope it can help you:http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/16867854

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908643/portlet-not-getting-deployed

Comment: @RongNK Yes. I did go through that forum post before along with a few others. I also checked the portlet declarations to ensure that they are consistent with v6.1.2. I also tried countless restarts after deleting corresponding install folders in autodeploy folder, undeloying from GF admin console and autodeploying. No change so far..

Comment: Did you try to deploy some portlet get from internet ?

Comment: Nice suggestion. I was about to try the same. I went ahead and downloaded one of the liferay demo war projects. It did deploy fine and I was able to see it in the list. That probably points the issue towards the war file I originally deployed. But the weird part is that it deploys just fine and shows up on the previous liferay build but not on this build. I've check to see if anything changed in the spec but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: So sorry, i think you should post in liferay's forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the Liferay build itself. The web.xml parser is faulty and breaks when comments/filters are present in web.xml. I got the latest patches from Liferay and that fixed it. The other way to fix it is to remove comments from web.xml and clean up the filter declarations properly.